# PostgreSQL: Group by, where, having with date interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, intervals, having

I'm trying to create a select group by dialed number and date. I'm using PostgreSQL and unfortunately I can not get a satisfactory result. 
(Sorry for my bad English, I'm using Google translator.)
I was trying to use this select:

```
SELECT
    callerid,
    to_no,
    is_fromoutside,
    -- starttime::date,
    -- to_char(starttime,'DD-MM-YYYY'),
    -- starttime,
    count(to_no),
    count(starttime)
FROM    callhistory3
where
    starttime between '2014/03/21' and '2014/04/21'
group by
    callerid, to_no, from_no, is_fromoutside, starttime
having
    is_fromoutside='f'
and callerid like '9030'
and to_no not like '9%'
order by starttime desc
;
```

Result:

```
"9030";"00262733319999";f;"2014-04-03";1
"9030";"00262733319999";f;"2014-04-03";1
"9030";"002614996837199";f;"2014-03-28";1
"9030";"032280840";f;"2014-03-28";1
"9030";"020156128";f;"2014-03-25";1
"9030";"0989168482";f;"2014-03-25";1
"9030";"0987131781";f;"2014-03-25";1
```

Comment: There is just not enough information. You'd have to make clear what you want how your query fails.

Comment: You have shown us the current output, but you haven't shown us the *required* output, so we can only guess. However, I notice you have both `to_no` and `count(to_no)` in the `SELECT` list; this doesn't make sense, because the output must still have a row to contain each different `to_no`.